# Can we kill the [data-security] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is a [data-security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-security) tag, with five questions:

> Data Security includes protecting data from unauthorized disclosure plus protecting the integrity of the data so it cannot be lost or altered without authorization

That sounds like the entire site scoope to me. Can I kill this tag for being to broad, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In looking at the questions using that tag, I'd have to agree it is entirely redundant. As usual I'll await a bit more of a consensus, but I'd be happy removing it.

Comment: BURN IT TO THE GROUND!

Comment: Would it be allright for me to go ahead and just remove the tag from all questions now?

Comment: I already did that :-)

Answer (score 3):

The data-security tag also seems to allow people to ask questions without thinking about what subset of data security they are looking for. That might be helpful for people with less knowledge; however, a minimal amount of searching would get better or at least more concise tag choices.

Comment: Well, if one can formulate a question in english, one should be able to find at least one fitting tag here: https://security.stackexchange.com/tags